Shot noise converted to digital value
I'm trying to estimate the standard deviation in the final digital value that originates from shot noise only, when using a standard smartphone camera. In high illumination, shot noise is supposed to dominate, and according to this document the standard deviation of the digital value is
$$
\sigma \simeq K \sqrt{\eta\mu_p},
$$ where

\$K\$ is the gain,
\$\nu\$ is the quantum efficiency, and
\$\mu_p\$ is the average number of incident photons.

I did a quick test where I take a video in normal illumination conditions, and I compute the mean and standard deviation of digital value of each pixel in time. I get a standard deviation of the order of unity for most pixels. This seems like a small value to me, as I expect the square root to be a large number, and \$K\$ to be larger than 1, is that not correct? If not why?
In any case, how can I estimate the amount of noise in the final digital value that originates specifically from shot noise?

Did you disable all post processing and noise reduction? Pixels that have been filtered to remove shot noise will not obey shot noise statistics.

For that matter, if the camera just has autoranging turned on then by definition the value of K varies.

I did not disable post processing, would the RAW format be what I need?

Shot noise originates from the statistical variability in photon counting. For a single detector in an ideal camera's image sensor taking a video of a still scene, the number of photons it captures and reads out for each image is unknown, but will average a certain value proportional to the radiated power on the detector times its quantum efficiency integrated over the EM spectrum. Any time you see the word "quantum" come up, be prepared for statistics and uncertainties.
The statistical distribution over multiple images (i.e. samples) follows a Poisson distribution. This is easy to analyze because the standard deviation of a Poisson distribution is the square root of the mean.
$$ \sigma = \sqrt{\mu}$$
If you replace the mean with the average number of photons times the quantum efficiency, you're left with the equation you presented without the gain term.

In any case, how can I estimate the amount of noise in the final digital value that originates specifically from shot noise?


Capture a large distribution of images of the same scene (100+). Keeping the scene irradiance constant is important or it will skew your results. Scientific camera characterization methods use an integrating sphere with a known radiant exitance that can be used to back-calculate the irradiance on the detector. For DIY photography, you can use a smooth, matte outdoor wall on a sunny day. Note 50-60 Hz noise from indoor lighting can affect the results, especially for fast shutter speeds. Also make sure your scene is not saturating your detector.

Turn off auto-ranging and auto-contrast features in the camera which can vary the gain value. Use a set gain/ISO and stick with it.

Use the camera's RAW file format which captures raw pixel data from the detector before it's processed. The camera runs several image quality improvement and compression algorithms in the background that you don't want if you're trying to measure inherent detector noise.

For each pixel in the captured set of images, generate a histogram and subtract the shot noise distribution based on the mean value of the pixel. What you're left with after doing this is your "other" temporal noise sources. The larger your dataset, the more accurate this method will be as long as you don't have changes in your scene. Your histogram should look something like this. If it doesn't, you have other noise sources.

Image Credit: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/poisson-distribution-and-shot-noise.976314/

If desired, do the same thing with the image processing/compression enabled on your camera and compare the results. From this you can see what effect the image processing/compression algorithms have on your image temporal noise, including shot noise. They will have noticeably different effects depending on what your scene looks like, and I'm not surprised by your results if your original dataset included this processing.


For more information on measuring camera noise and performance parameters, I suggest the book Photon Transfer by James R Janesick.
